# Strange Behaviour in Production with deletion of AccountShare record with Row Cause as Manual

Tags: apex, person-accounts, apex-managed-sharing, accountshare

As per documentation.

> If a user transfers ownership of a record, Salesforce deletes any manual shares created by the original record owner, which can cause users to lose access. When account ownership is transferred, manual shares created by the original account owner on child records, such as opportunities and cases, are also deleted.

So for this we implemented a queueable job, which restores the accountShare record.

We queried it in before Update whenever an owner change happens `SELECT Id, AccountAccessLevel, OpportunityAccessLevel, CaseAccessLevel, AccountId, RowCause, UserOrGroupId FROM AccountShare WHERE AccountId IN :accIds AND RowCause = 'Manual'`

And restore them with a queueable job.

```
for (AccountShare reason : reasons) {
    reason.Id = null;
}
List<Database.SaveResult> resultList = DMLService.doInsertWithoutSharingPartially(reasons);
```

The strange behavior is, it works sometimes, but does not work sometimes. With no exception or governor limits of any kind, as this would be caught in our finalizer too and logged.

In our org account owner gets changed frequently. I am suspecting may be internal sharing of Salesforce may be taking more time and by that time the queuable job would have restored account share. After that when internal sharing is done, it will again delete the Account Manual Share record.

But not sure, anyone faced this issue, if yes how to resolve this?

**IDEA**

1. Write a batch which runs every 15 minutes and verifies if account share exists, if not create Account Share records. (Cons : Every time batch has to to run on all the records , which is in millions).
2. Use Account team members (Cons: Even this gets deleted when Owner change happens via Apex, here also same issue may come)

Comment: Please check if your Account Sharing requirements can be fulfilled by Apex Managed Sharing instead of 'Manual' Sharing. Apex managed sharing is maintained (not deleted) when record owner changes. So no need of restoring share records.

Comment: Even apex managed sharing gets deleted when owner changes. And i am already using apex managed sharing . In fact all sharing with row cause as `Manual` gets deleted and as account is standard object we cannot use any other row cause.